# How to return more than one element list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

i have a stored procedure that will return all the records from my database, and I wanted to filter that result using linq, but the problem it will return only one record, though I have two records to be returned.

> CustomerController

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
        private CustomerController()
        {

            var _data = ViewCustomer();
            if (_data.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                customers = (from DataRow _dr in _data.Rows
                             select new CustomerModel()
                             {
                                 custId = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["custId"]),
                                 custName = Convert.ToString(_dr["custName"]),
                                 custAddress = Convert.ToString(_dr["custAddress"]),
                                 custContact = Convert.ToString(_dr["custContact"]),
                                 custStatus = Convert.ToString(_dr["custStatus"]),
                                 agentId = Convert.ToInt32(_dr["agentId"]),
                                 agentContact = Convert.ToString(_dr["agentContact"])
                             }).ToList();
            }
        }

        // GET: api/Customer
        public List<CustomerModel> Get()
        {
            return customers;
        }

        // GET: api/Customer/5
        public CustomerModel Get(string num)
        {
            return customers.Where(x => x.agentContact.Equals(num)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

> DataRepository

```
 namespace DataLibrary.Repository
    {
        public class DataRepository
        {

            public static DataTable ViewCustomer()
            {
                try
                {
                    DataLayers CustData = new DataLayers();
                    CustData.cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    CustData.SQL = "CustomerStoredProcedure";
                    CustData.paramVal = new string[,]
                    {
                        { "@custId", ""},
                        { "@custName", ""},
                        { "@custAddress", ""},
                        { "@custContact", ""},
                        { "@custStatus", ""},
                        { "@agentId", ""},
                        { "@statement", "Select"}
                    };
                    return CustData.GetData();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> This is the stored proc.

```
create procedure CustomerStoredProcedure
     (
    custId int(11),
    custName varchar(100),
    custAddress varchar(100),
    custContact varchar(20),
    custStatus varchar(20),
    agentId int(11),
    statement varchar(30)
    )
    begin
    if statement = 'Select' then
    select c.custId, c.custName, c.custAddress, c.custContact, c.custStatus, c.agentId,
    a.agentId, a.agentContact 
    from customer c 
    inner join agent a on c.agentId = a.agentId;
    elseif statement = 'Insert' then
    insert into customer ( custName, custAddress, custContact, custStatus, agentId) 
    values (custName, custAddress, custContact, custStatus, agentId);
    elseif statement = 'Update' then
    update customer set custName = custName, custAddress = custAddress,
    custContact = custContact, custStatus = custStatus, agentId = agentId where
    custtId = custId;
    elseif statement = 'Delete' then
    delete from customer where custId = custId;
    end if;
```

> This is my DataLayers

```
public class DataLayers
    {
        public static string success = "Record successfully added!";
        public static string failed = "Error: Data could not added, Please check your inputted data(s)!";

        public CommandType cmdType { get; set; }
        public string SQL { get; set; }
        public string[,] paramVal { get; set; }

        public static MySqlConnection Config()
        {
            var conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }

        public DataTable GetData()
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(this.SQL, Config());
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            if (this.paramVal != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= paramVal.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(this.paramVal[i, 0].ToString().Trim(), this.paramVal[i, 1].ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataAdapter.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            Config().Close();
            return dt;
        }

        public DataTable GetData(bool Error)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(this.SQL, Config());
                cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                if (this.paramVal != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= paramVal.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(this.paramVal[i, 0].ToString().Trim(), this.paramVal[i, 1].ToString().Trim());
                    }
                }
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                dataAdapter.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                Config().Close();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Error");
                dt.Columns.Add("Message");
                dt.Rows.Add("Error: ", ex.Message.Replace("Tables", "Table").Replace("MySql", "Database"));
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

> This is my DataRepository

```
 public class DataRepository
    {
        public static DataTable ViewAgent()
        {
            try
            {

                DataLayers AgentData = new DataLayers();
                AgentData.cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                AgentData.SQL = "AgentStoredProcedure";
                AgentData.paramVal = new string[,]
                {
                    { "@agentId", "" },
                    { "@agentName", ""},
                    { "@agentAddress", ""},
                    { "@agentContact", ""},
                    { "@agentStatus", ""},
                    { "@catId", ""},
                    { "@statement", "Select"}
                };
                return AgentData.GetData();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static DataTable ViewCustomer()
        {
            try
            {
                DataLayers CustData = new DataLayers();
                CustData.cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                CustData.SQL = "CustomerStoredProcedure";
                CustData.paramVal = new string[,]
                {
                    { "@custId", ""},
                    { "@custName", ""},
                    { "@custAddress", ""},
                    { "@custContact", ""},
                    { "@custStatus", ""},
                    { "@agentId", ""},
                    { "@statement", "Select"}
                };
                return CustData.GetData();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

> return all records

[image]

> return only one record, (wrong result)

[image]

> this is the correct record result

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the underlying implementation of the `procedure/data layer` it is hard to say what is wrong with the outcome. But my guess would be either there is a `Where` condition in your select statement that is restricting to a single record or there is a `default` limit of `1` record in your `DataLayers` class implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many questions.

- Why do you have a private constructor?
- What is `DataLayers`, is this some homegrown data access library?
- Why doesn't the stored procedure allow for searching on `@agentContact`?
- Why load all data from the database, upon controller construction, instead of filtering on demand?

And so on. But assuming you're stuck with this approach, you've defined the wrong signature and logic for your requirements. You want to return a list instead of a single item:

```
public List<CustomerModel> Get(string num)
{
    return customers.Where(x => x.agentContact.Equals(num)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Now I post all my code Sir..Sorry I am newbie in C# MVC that's why don't have enough idea on how to make a clean codes..